# Can firestore data be examined at client by app users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-security

I am making a react-native App with Firebase backend.
User profile info is stored in Firestore unencypted under "`Users`" collection, like so:

```json
Users : {
  <uid1> : {     // this is a document
    uid : <uid1>,
    name : "Sundar Pichai",
    dob : 428535558167,
    email : "sundar.pichai@google.com",
    photo : "https://api.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/time-100-Sundar-Pichai.jpg",
    company : "Google",
  },
}
```

Client app will fetch documents of some users, and the app will show `public` data (only limited data) on screen, like `name` and `photo`.
App will not show other private info like `dob`, `email` etc unless the client user, has some specific privilages.

I am worried that if the entire document is anyways available at the client, can someone do a postmortem of the packets/data received and be able to read all the data fields ?
Specially if its a Web App.

---

One solution that I can think of, is using sepatate documents for public and private views. But that means: [1] Almost double the read count, and [2] i cannot query public info using a key that's only in private doc, like `dob`

```json
UsersPublicInfo : {
  <uid1> : {     // this is a document
    uid : <uid1>,
    name : "Sundar Pichai",
    photo : "https://api.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/time-100-Sundar-Pichai.jpg",
    company : "Google",
  },
}

UsersPrivateInfo : {
  <uid1> : {     // this is a document
    dob : 428535558167,
    email : "sundar.pichai@google.com",
  },
}
```

Am I worrying too much about this data examination ?
Is it an issue for data security ?

PS: It's actually not a firebase specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firestore, if someone can read a document, they will always get all of the data in that document.  It's not possible to protect data per field, if you are allowing client apps to directly access the database.

It's common to split public and private data into different collection with different security rules, for the reasons you mentioned.  This is how you make sure users should only have access to the specific data you want them to have.